# Corruption when passing struct into function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, pass-by-reference

So i have this struct and i ve set the value of front to 0, but when it enters a function the value jumps to a really high and seemingly random number eg "1868038144". I have no clue why this is happening and how i can fix it.
here's the structure of the struct:

```
#define MQA 3 //Defines the maximum amount of queues
#define MQS 5 //Defines the maximum queue size of each message queue (amount of messages)
#define MLN 200 //Defines the maximum size of a message


typedef struct MessQ{//A single message queue
    char messages[MQS][MLN];
    char id[50];
}MessQ_t;


typedef struct MsgQs{//An array of message queues
    MessQ_t * queue;
    int front; //helps define the next queue to be added
    int back;
}MsgQs_t;
```

This is the function I'm passing it into:

```
//creates a new queue and which is assigned an identifier passed as argument
void createQ(MsgQs_t *mq, char ident[50]){
    printf("This front: %d\n ",mq->front);
    if(mq->front<=MQA){
        printf("THIS IS THE FRONT %d\n",mq->front);
        strcpy( mq->queue[mq->front].id, "yes");
        mq->front++;//Increments this to keep track of where the next queue should be put
        printf("THIS IS THE FRONT %d\n",mq->front);
    }
    else{printf("Out of room \n");}
}
```

And this is the code im using so to refer to it in the main:

```
printf("THIS IS THE FRONT %d\n",msq.front);
char ide[50]="ThisIsTheId";
createQ(&msq, ide);
```

Comment: You're best off by giving us a complete, preferably compile-able, Minimal Reproducible Example. Without that it is difficult to say if the problem is with the code you provided us or elsewhere in your program.

Comment: In `MsgQs_t`, `MessQ_t * queue;` in an uninitialized pointer. In `void createQ(MsgQs_t *mq, ...` you are passing `mq` by value, so any changes made in `create` are lost when the function returns and never seen back in the caller. Both errors are *unrelated*, but equally fatal. Also, curious you `#define` proper constants for all values except `char id[50];` - why no constant for `50`?

Comment: SO has a blurb on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or there's an external site on how to create an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Using a debugger can help you to find the line where there is problem.